# Leaflet.js localization request text on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

When I deploy my leaflet app to ios, the system asks me whether the user trusts application `/private/var/mobile/Containers/bundle/Application/BLABLABLANUMBERS234234/www/index.html`

to use the current location?
How can I

1. Replace the path with the application name?
2. Save the decision for the future? It keeps asking me every time when I start the app.

I guess Android would be similar?

Thanks 
EL